# finding minimum value of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, min

from what I've learned, I should be getting the min value of the array, but instead I am getting a large negative number that doesn't exist in my array.

```
int size;
size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

int min;
min = array[0];

for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    if(array[i] < min){
        min = array[i];
    }
}
```

But for some reason I am getting a large negative number: -9.25596e+061

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
                //^^^^array index out of bound, since array index starts from 0
   if(array[i] < min){
      min = array[i];
   }
}
```

You should only compare elements in your array. You tried to access memory not belonging to the array, so you have strange values in that memory.

Your code should look like this:

```
int min = array[0];
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
   if(array[i] < min){
      min = array[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: To elaborate, C arrays are indexed from 0, not 1, so the first element is at `[0]`, and the last element is at `[length-1]`

Comment: lol Thanks had a dumb moment there...I've been coding for 8 hrs straight.

Comment: @tacp can you help me with my avg calculator loop, for some reason I am getting a negative number again like before that should come up

Answer (score 0):

When doing your comparison, `<= size` means you're iterating 1 past the end of the array. It's most likely picking up some really huge garbage value and that becomes the minimum.

Use `for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) { /* ... */ }` to get what you need.